# setting a toggleView text in getVIew() function

Tags: android, togglebutton, getview

I am doing this in my getView function but the problem is when I scroll up and down, all of the toggleView get ON even if the "IF" part doesn't work. I've used a breakpoint to check whether IF works there but it doesn't, still all of the buttons gets checked. I'm setting buttons checked just here

```
if((Btns[position].equals("1")) && (!tb.isChecked())){
    tb.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: I think more information is necessary here.  Can you provide more of the adapter code and the layout file.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with how Android reuses ListView items. An easy fix would be to put `tb.setChecked(false);` before that `if` statement. That'll explicitly make sure its off, unless it passes the `if`.

Comment: are you the position is a string and not an int?

Comment: position is int , as default parameter in the getView function

Comment: @andrewBrooke Thank You man it worked perfectly, you are totally right that was some problem with android listview usability . fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

You can initially set the button to be not checked. This will make it so the button in all list items will be unchecked, unless it passes your if statement.

```
tb.setChecked(false);
if((Btns[position].equals("1")) && (!tb.isChecked())){
    tb.setChecked(true);
}
```